# Interpret \n within irb or script/console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When using something like `object.methods.sort.to_yaml` I'd like to have irb interpret the \n characters rather than print them.

I currently get the following output:

```
--- \n- "&"\n- "*"\n- +\n- "-"\n- "<<"\n- <=>\n ...
```

What I'd like is something similar to this:

```
--- 
 - "&"
 - "*"
 - +
 - "-"
 - "<<"
 - <=>
```

Is this possible? Is there another method I can be calling which will interpret the string perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefix your output with `puts`:

```
> puts object.methods.sort.to_yaml
--- 
 - "&"
 - "*"
 - +
 - "-"
 - "<<"
 - <=>
 => nil
```

Comment: By default, irb calls the inspect method to print the object, which, for a string, escapes special characters such as \n. Print and puts interpret special characters and call to_s on non-strings.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to start irb with the noinspect option:

```
C:\>irb --noinspect
irb(main):001:0> Object.methods.to_yaml
=> ---
- instance_method
- yaml_tag_read_class
.....
- constants
- is_a?

irb(main):002:0>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby *yaml* library includes the "**y**" command, which takes care of both the yamlizing and the formatting:

```
y object.methods.sort
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just irb -- I don't think you can control the `return` formatting.

You can still use `print` or `puts` to display it as you want.